ZED 2 initialization - coordinate system w/o internal IMU system
I am using a ZED 2 with a Jetson for a robotic application, where the camera is mounted near the TCP and thus changes orientation. I want to get the raw depth data in some coordinate frame inside the optical centre, and aligned with the camera.
However, it seems like the data i get is flipped based on the orientation of the ZED with the direction of gravity - something i absolutetly don't want for my application. Google search and documentation brought me to the conclusion, that this is some default setting that can be disabled. However, i have to admit, i just don't know how. I tried various intialization parameter settings, the latest of which is (using python)
…
import pyzed.sl as sl
from zed_camera.camera import *
…
init_params = sl.InitParameters()
init_params.camera_resolution = sl.RESOLUTION.HD720
init_params.coordinate_units = sl.UNIT.METER
init_params.coordinate_system = sl.COORDINATE_SYSTEM.IMAGE
init_params.depth_stabilization = False
camera = Zed_Camera(init_params)
…

The depth_stabilization is usually activated, and activates positional tracking in the background, which causes alignment of the cameras y-axis with gravity. However, even disabling this, apparently did not give me the actual raw depth coordinates in the optical centre.
point clouds at different camera orientations
In the image, the first two point clouds (blue/red) are taken with the camera basically looking at 40° towards the ground. For the red point cloud, the camera was rotated (as in a wrist rotation) by 60° w.r.t the blue pose. The yellow point cloud is a rotation of 60° in the opposite direction. Nevertheless, the red/blue cloud are somehow aligned internally, which is already undesired behaviour, and the third, yellow cloud then shows the rotation.
Any help on how to actually get the optical centre depth data w/o internal coordinate flips would be highly appreciated!
Edit: Image description
